# Custom implementation of UICollectionViewCell makes cells invisible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

For the sake of context I'm developing a calendar app with 3 different views. Day, Month and Year View.

In order to display the days I've decided to use a `UICollectionView` with a custom implementation of `UICollectionViewCell` (so that I'm able to customize the aspect of each cell).

On the `init` of my `NSObject` CtrlCalendar class I register 3 cell Classes like this:

```
//Used for the yearView
[self.grid registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"monthCell"];

//Used for the monthView
[self.grid registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forC ellWithReuseIdentifier:@"dayCell"];

//Used for the dayView
[self.grid registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"hourCell"];
```

Than, on `collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath` I'm doing as follows:

```
CollectionViewCell *cell = nil;
if ([self.currentDisplayType isEqualToString:@"monthView"]) {
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"dayCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.month = [self.displayingViews get:indexPath.section];
    if (indexPath.row + 1 >= self.month.firstWeekDay && indexPath.row + 1 < self.month.numberOfDays + (self.month.firstWeekDay)) {
        NSDateComponents *tempDay = [self.calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:self.month.date];
        cell.date = [self.dateHelper addToDate:self.month.date days:(int)(tempDay.day + indexPath.row - self.month.firstWeekDay)];
        cell.cellTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)(tempDay.day + indexPath.row + 1 - self.month.firstWeekDay)];
        cell.cellTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        if ([[self.dateHelper addToDate:self.month.date days:(indexPath.row + 1 - self.month.firstWeekDay)] isEqualToDate:self.today]) {
            cell.cellTitle.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        cell.separator.hidden = NO;
        cell.contentView.hidden = NO;

    } else {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
```

And finally here is my implementation of `CollectionViewCell`:

```
@interface CollectionViewCell ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *cellTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *titleText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *separator;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date;

@end

@implementation CollectionViewCell

@synthesize cellTitle;
@synthesize titleText;
@synthesize separator;
@synthesize date;

- (void)dealloc {
    [cellTitle release];
    [titleText release];
    [separator release];
    [date release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.cellTitle = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds] autorelease];
        self.cellTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.cellTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        self.separator = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (self.frame.size.height - 0.25), self.frame.size.width, 0.5)] autorelease];
        self.separator.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.separator];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.cellTitle];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.cellTitle.text = nil;
    self.separator.hidden = YES;
    [self.cellTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    //the presence of this line is explained after the edit bellow
    [self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}

@end
```

The first time I run the app, the Month View is configured as expected, but as soon as it performs the dequeue, the cells turn blank.

After some debugging I found that the `CollectionViewCell`'s `cellTitle` property is correctly set. The problem resides in the fact that after the dequeue the labels are hidden for some reason.

I know this is long question, but if you can help in anyway or know someone who can help please let me know!

Thanks a lot!

For clarification of what the problem is I'm adding some screens

**Before scrolling:**
[image: **Before scrolling**]

**After scrolling:**
[image: **After scrolling**]

**UPDATE 1**

As @Alessandro Chiarotto answered, the 
`[self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]`
does make the cells empty. The caveat here is that I need that selector to remove from the cells some UILabels I'm adding to the `yearView`.

My `yearView` UICollection has 12 cells (one for each month). Each cell than has the number of UILabels as the days in each month. I'm adding this UILabels from the `collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath` like this:

```
for (int d = 1; d < self.month.numberOfDays; d++) {
    UILabel *day = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:dayRect] autorelease];
    day.text = currentDay;
    [cell addSubview:day];
}
```

If i don't perform the selector in `prepareForReuse`, after scrolling the view I have all the `day` labels in duplicate in each month cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. As @Alessandro said in his answer the `[self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];` was removing everything from the cell, therefore making it blank.

That would be it if it weren't for another aspect of the problem.

As I said in my question Update, I need that selector in order to remove some UILabels that are being added in the `yearView`. Those labels are the days in each month cell.

**Solution:**

I added a `UIView` property to the `CollectionViewCell` that has a frame equal to the cell's bounds. I than add the UILabels to this view and on the `prepareForReuse` I perform the `removeFromSuperView` on the `self.labelsView.subviews`. It works like a charm.

The correct implementation of `prepareForReuse` would be:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
     self.cellTitle.text = nil;
     self.separator.hidden = YES;
    [self.cellTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.labelsView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you scroll the collection then `prepareForReuse` will be called. In `prepareForReuse` you have the following call:

```
[self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

this will remove all the subviews of the cell (UILabel and so on).

At this point your cell will "white"...

Comment: Thanks, I just realised that solves this questions but raises another one. I'm updating the question!